# Converting NSString to NSDate gives nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

```
NSString *dateString2 = record.trigger_end_date;
NSLog(@"dateString2  is%@%@",record.trigger_end_date,dateString2);
NSDateFormatter *formatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
formatter2.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
NSDate *date2 = [formatter2 dateFromString:dateString2];
NSLog(@"date2 is%@",date2);
```

Here I'm getting log for  `NSLog(@"dateString2  is%@%@",record.trigger_end_date,dateString2);` as `dateString2  is2014-04-30T00:00:002014-04-30T00:00:00`
but  `NSLog(@"date2 is%@",date2); is date2 is(null)`

Comment: A trivial question. It is clearly explained in the documentation.

Comment: I have a feeling it's been asked before as well....

Comment: Did you try to google?

Comment: Maybe we end with a retain cycle... ;)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I would close this topic as a duplicate, but I can't decide which other topic to choose (there are so many questions asking for the same), so here is an answer:

`formatter2.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";`

Comment: Would the ones downvoting this answer please comment on the reason for  downvoting?

Answer (score 0):

i know this question false in duplicate category & i flagged it as well. but i am answering here with explanation, if in case OP does not get the references .

```
 NSString *dateString = @"2014-04-30T00:00:00"; //input string
 NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
 [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];// fomatter in your case
 NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
 NSLog(@"date is%@",date);

 output - date is2014-04-29 18:30:00 +0000
```